# recurrence in numpy / numexpr python

Tags: numpy, numexpr

I have an array `x=np.ones(1000)` and would like to perform  operations
on this based on recurrence formulae:

```
    x[i]= f(x[i-1], x[i-2])
```

What is the fastest way to do it in a vectorize way ?

I know that `xx= ne.evaluate(xx1*xx2)` can only manage already filled array.

Comment: Could you share more details about the func `f`?

Comment: f is using standard math function like sin, cos, exp,..

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial way, at least for some functions:

```
list[:,1:]= np.exp(hlist)  
list = np.cumprod(list, axis = 1)
```

with 
f(x) = f(x-1)*exp(a*x)

I think generic cum would be useful